Django database migrate
It uses my own user and permissions model in Django, but the database consists of Django's own models.
I use my own authorization model in Django, but when I migrate, auth_permissions occur in the database. Can I prevent this? What can I do to prevent it from occurring?
class Permission(models.Model):

add_product = models.BooleanField(default=False)
add_category = models.BooleanField(default=False)


What's the problem with keeping both? The permission model from auth is used by the admin site anyway?

I did'nt save anything with admin.py i created own my dashboard I just don't know why it should occur and what should'nt happen so that it does'nt

Again my question is what's the problem with keeping both the models? Just don't use the one from auth? As long as you have the auth app in your installed apps setting the table will get created in the database. A table will get created for the model in your app as well so I don't see what the problem is, you'll just have an extra table you don't really use.

The problem is that auth_permissions occur in migration processes, but I create it automatically, I want to use my own permissions model, I want the properties of an empty table in the database.
